# Getting Catategory / Taxonomy Description on Non-archive Pages

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

Can you pull in the description of a custom tax on pages other than the taxonomy-(custom-tax).php

i.e on the home page you want to show the description of a custom tax.

This works on the aforementioned archive page but nowhere else:

```
<?php echo term_description( '', get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the term id to replace `''` and the taxonomy name to replace `get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )`.

```
echo term_description( $term_id, 'your_custom_tax_name_here' );
```

P.S. Have you ever heard about [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description)?

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work <?php echo term_description( $term_id, 'test-tax' ) ); ?> on the home page for example, crashes the page...

Comment: That is probably a syntax error. You have an extra closing parenthesis in your the code in your comment. Try `<?php echo term_description( $term_id, 'test-tax' ); ?>`